# How to debug the GUI locking up?

Tags: 20.04, gui, debugging

At seemingly random time, my GUI locks up. I can generally recover from this (sort of) by getting another session via ssh and running `sudo init 3 ; sudo init 5` but I lose any work in progress in all of my running GUI apps.

- What could be causing this?
- How can I identify the problem?
- How can I make this quit happening?

I've searched for a few obvious things but all the results I've found so far are "how to recover" and none of them "how to make this not happen again".

A few other facts:

- The system end up almost entirely un-responsive to the keyboard/mouse; even `ctrl`+`alt`+`F#` and `caps-lock` gets no response.
- If it happens while I'm playing a video, the visual portion of the video freezes but the audio usually continues for at least a few minutes.
- If I wait long enough, it *sometimes* recovers and sometimes I see indications that it process at least a few inputs from the keyboard/mouse (e.g. the cursor move a few pixels, changes type or that kind of thing).
- Those `init` commands take much longer to run while recovering than they do at other times.
- This has happened both before and after upgrading to 20.04 (I think I was on 18.04 before).

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Further evidence suggests this was somehow related to some specific chrome tab: after each restart I'd restore the same set of tabs, but since I flushed a bunch of them, the problem hasn't happened. -- But that seems strange in and of it self.

Comment: Well, things started failing again (but maybe not as often?). Yet further evidence suggests the *video drivers* were a more root cause: switching from the open source drivers to the proprietary nVidia drivers seems to have resolved to the situation, at least for the last week or so.